# Action Bar list navigation title

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How can I add title to Action Bar's list navigation? Is it possible? I'm using Action Bar Sherlock.

How it works:

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16134555/list_nav_1.png]

I want to get this result:

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16134555/list_nav_2.pn]

Activity:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.menu, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

R.array.menu:

```
<string-array name="menu">
    <item>Menu</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Please post your action bar code

Comment: There should already be the default application name as your title.

Comment: I added source code. @JaredBurrows - I know, but I want to make list navigation without repeating Menu as title and menu item. Please compare first and second photo.

Comment: Whether or not it's technically possible, wouldn't this design violate the expected UX of an Android Spinner control? How would the user be able to see what item is currently selected? It's your app, obviously, but I'd strongly consider whether such a thing is truly necessary.

Comment: I understand what you are asking. "Menu" should be the "Main" screen. So when you click on the navigation list and select another option it should change. Check out the Google+ application. Simply make, "Menu" your "Main"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a custom `ArrayAdapter` and a `getView` method that always sets the same text, the menu title.

```
class ActionBarArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context mContext;

    public ActionBarArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, null);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1))
                .setText("Menu");
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is how to initialize the `Adapter`:

```
ActionBarArrayAdapter list = new ActionBarArrayAdapter(context,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu));
list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```